# Epistemic logic puzzle: Still don't know

Tags: logic

Apologies if this is not appropriate for the site; I thought people might enjoy it.

In the spirit of [Cheryl's rational gifts](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1241197/413), here is an epistemic logic puzzle that I used on the final exam in my logic class this semester.  I'll post a solution later, if necessary, but I expect we'll get some quality answers very soon.

> Suppose that Alice and Bob are each given a different fraction, of the form $\frac{1}{n}$, where $n$ is a positive integer, and it is commonly known to them that they each know only their own number and that it is different from the other one. The following conversation ensues.
>
> **JDH**     *I privately gave you each a different rational number of the form $\frac{1}{n}$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Who has the larger number?*
>
> **Alice**      *I don't know.*
>
> **Bob**     *I don't know either.*
>
> **Alice**    *I still don't know.*
>
> **Bob**    *Suddenly, now I know who has the larger number.*
>
> **Alice**    *In that case, I know both numbers.*

What numbers were they given?

Comment: I'd prefer to give Alice and Bob positive integers and ask for the smaller integer.

Comment: @ChargeShivers I did a version like that here: http://jdh.hamkins.org/now-i-know/. I thought the fractional one is getting a little closer to Cheryl's rational gifts: http://jdh.hamkins.org/transfinite-epistemic-logic-puzzle-challenge/

Comment: I've posted my solution at http://jdh.hamkins.org/still-dont-know-an-epistemic-logic-puzzle/#solution. Both Henry and Saulspatz got it right below. I accepted saulspatz, since he was earlier (by one second!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Alice had 1/1, she'd know the winner at her first turn.

If Bob had 1/1 or 1/2, he'd know the winner at his first turn.

If Alice had 1/2 or 1/3, she'd know the winner at her second turn.

Now Bob knows who wins, so he must have 1/3 or 1/4.  If Alice's number is smaller than 1/4, she can't tell which Bob has.  So Alice has 1/4, and Bob 1/3.

Answer (score 3):

- ***Alice***    I don't know. So Alice does not have $\frac11$
- ***Bob***    I don't know either. So Bob does not have $\frac11$ or $\frac12$
- ***Alice***    I still don't know. So Alice does not have $\frac12$ or $\frac13$
- ***Bob***    Suddenly, now I know who has the larger number. So Bob has $\frac13$ or $\frac14$
- ***Alice***    In that case, I know both numbers. If Alice knows which Bob has then she has the other, and (from earlier) she does not have $\frac13$

So Alice has $\frac14$ and Bob has $\frac13$

Answer (score 0):

If Alice had $1/2$ she'd know. So she doesn't.

Bob now knows that. If he had $1/2$ or $1/3$ he'd know. So he doesn't.

If Alice had $1/3$ she'd know. So she doesn't.

Bob now knows. So he must have $1/4$ and have the smaller number.

Alice knows that and knows her number, so she knows both.