# Is this transfinite Cheryl's birthday problem correct?

Tags: logic, ordinals

I found [Joel David Hamkins' riddle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241197/a-transfinite-epistemic-logic-puzzle-what-numbers-did-cheryl-give-to-albert-and) quite fun and wanted to construct one for a larger ordinal. I removed the fraction aspect since I think that would add too much difficulty to this version. However, I'm not 100% sure that the puzzle is unambiguous/correct as stated so I'm hoping people can point out if there's an error. I'll spoiler the answer in case anyone wants to think about it independently first.

> Cheryl is throwing a birthday party, and as an excellent host decides to give each guest a gift. As a not so great host, her gift to each of them consists of one of the two following items:
>
> - A month of the year
> - A pair consisting of a month and a finite length, non-empty sequence of non-negative integers
>
> Two gifts may be compared for "size" as follows:
>
> - If both gifts are just months, the later month is larger
> - If one gift is a month and the other is a pair, the month is larger
> - If both are pairs and one has a later month, the pair with the later month is larger
> - If both months are equal, sequences are compared first by length (longer sequences are bigger), then lexicographically
>
> Albert and Bernard arrive and receive distinct gifts, which they each keep hidden.
>
> **Cheryl**: Which of you do you think has the larger gift?
>
> **Albert**: I don't know
>
> **Bernard**: Neither do I
>
> **Albert**: I still don't know
>
> **Bernard**: And still either do I
>
> **Cheryl**: Well, no matter how long you two go back and forth like that you'll never know who has the bigger gift
>
> **Albert**: Despite that hint, I still don't know
>
> **Bernard**: Neither do I
>
> **Albert**: I still don't know
>
> **Bernard**: And still neither do I
>
> **Cheryl**: Let me call that last statement $S_0$, and say that no matter how many times we went back and forth with you two saying you don't know, and me saying $S_0$, you still wouldn't know who has the bigger gift
>
> **Albert**: Despite that hint I still don't know, and also I find that subscript a bit ominous
>
> **Bernard**: I also don't know
>
> **Cheryl**: Call my last statement $S_1$, and now I will tell you that no matter how many times we alternate with you two saying you don't know, and myself saying $S_0$ or $S_1$, you still will not know who has the larger number
>
> **Albert**: And yet I still don't know
>
> **Bernard**: Me neither
>
> **Cheryl**: Let me now define $S_n$ inductively to be the statement that no matter how many times we alternate with you two saying you don't know, and myself saying any $S_k$ for $k < n$, you two will still not know who has the larger gift. I now tell you that all statements $S_n$ are true.
>
> **Albert**: Even still, I don't know who received the bigger gift
>
> **Bernard**: Me neither
>
> **Albert**: Ah I now know who has the bigger gift!
>
> **Bernard**: Oh! Now I know as well, and also I know what gift you got
>
> **Albert**: Then I know what gift you got as well
>
> What gift did they each receive?

I believe that with this set of utterances, the solution is that

> Albert received a pair of February, and a one element sequence: $[1]$, and Bernard received a pair of February and $[2]$

My intention is that the gifts are ordered with order type

> $\omega^\omega \cdot 12 + 12$. The $+ 12$ is added as a confounder, since I think the obvious wrong answer would be that all pairs are ruled out so they both must each have only a month.

Edit: Let me also add my reasoning so that someone can comment directly on whether it is correct:

> I believe that each "I don't know" rules out the lowest available final number of a finite-sequence for the speaker, so the initial I don't knows are stepping through (January, $[1]$), (January, $[2]$) etc.
>
>  They also eliminate the month-only gifts in descending order.

> Cheryl asserting the truth of $S_n$ increments the lowest possible $n$-th element of the sequence in a (January, sequence) pair by 1 (and $S_0$ rules out all month-only gifts).
>  Therefore, since all $S_n$ are true, exactly the pairs with January as their month are ruled out, so we're left with the just the version on the natural numbers (the 1 element sequences)

Comment: Can the integers in a sequence be negative?

Comment: Ah great catch, they should be natural numbers let me edit that.